# Optionmenu/Entry combination in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hej, I want to produce an entry field (for directory paths) that also has the dropdown ability of an optionmenu (stating the 5 last used directories). It is basically supposed to look like the solution MATLAB uses. How do I go about that? I need the ability to manually change the path, so a plain optionmenu with a browse button won t do. Is there anything like that out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ttk.Combobox widget, http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#combobox (or http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.htm). Using this you can set default values, but you are also able to write in the entry a new value.

```
combobox = ttk.Combobox(parent)
combobox['values'] = five_last_dirs_tuple
combobox['state'] = 'normal'

# later... 

path = combobox.get()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Ended up using the Pmw version, since it made for less changes in the source code, but you gave me the idea!